# Managing Partners without the use of Communities

Tags: api, leads, partner-communities

I have recently implemented Salesforce to our company and we would need to manage some of our partners. Ie. Allow Partners to update leads that are assigned to them through Salesforce. The Partner Communities feature in Salesforce is above our budget so we cannot purchase this feature. Does anyone have any ideas on an alternative on how we can manage this requirement without using Partner Communities?

Comment: Just buy the licenses, dude. See if you can chat up your salesforce account executive for a smaller introductory package or something, otherwise you risk spending up on custom development to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Unfortunately Purchasing Communities is not an option. I am looking for alternatives.

Comment: There are no alternatives. Salesforce will audit your system after 6 months of use and you'll be forever to upgrade your licensing if you do a workaround.  There's a reason they charge you for it. If you want the functionality, you have to pay for it.